# var reads HTML code as STRING

Tags: php, html

Very simply, i want to make a variable reads the html code as string ,, i mean dont execute it (run it) .

the problem with the code is : i have a html file , and i want to get the content of it , and make some `preg_replace` for it (run a function on the html code), the problem is i cant use `preg_replace`, or any another function because the html code is executed by php (php reads the html code)..

i wish you understand me, i want something like `highlight_string`, but it save the html code in the variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

you're probably trying to include or require the HTML code.
which is incorrect since it is evaluated as part of the source.

instead, use a function such as `file_get_contents()` to read the file into a string.

Comment: PHP is a templating engine :)

Comment: yes i did,, im already using file_get_contents, but the problem is when i print the var, it give me the executed code .. an example ... the file of html contant **'<p>test test</p>'** ... when i get the content and 'echo file_get_contents($filepath)' the php return **test test** ..

Comment: I dont think you have a PHP issue.  Do you need to view source on your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents()` as @David Chan suggested and then pass the result through `htmlentities()`... it converts the characters to HTML entities (i.e., `<` to `&lt;`).

```
$getTheContent = file_get_contents($filepath);
echo htmlentities($getTheContent);
```

It should return the code, not executed.

Comment: Thank you, its good idea .. but the problem is i have a regex patterns , and the regex patterns should find the <> so here is the problem ,,, i want the way which using in <form> ,, when it send the inputs it never executed. Thank you.